# How to get the text used for entity extraction in wit.ai?

Tags: nlp, wit.ai

If the text is "What's the weather in chicago today?", wit.ai returns the following entities

```
"entities": {
"location": [
  {
    "confidence": 0.9483763321862972,
    "type": "value",
    "value": "Chicago",
    "suggested": true
  }
],
"datetime": [
  {
    "confidence": 0.9499492133072054,
    "type": "value",
    "value": "2016-12-13T00:00:00.000-08:00",
    "grain": "day",
    "values": [
      {
        "type": "value",
        "value": "2016-12-13T00:00:00.000-08:00",
        "grain": "day"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

}

How can I get wit.ai to also return the text corresponding to each entity extraction, in this case "chicago" for wit/location and "today" for wit/datetime

For a user defined entity, I know I can do it by defining the search strategy as free-text & keyword. But there is no option to change that for wit/datetime.

Comment: any updates @sera ?

Comment: wit.ai now gives you the start/end character length